# Taking derivative of objective function

Tags: optimization, nonlinear-optimization, least-squares, parameter-estimation

Given $x_t$ and $c_n$, the objective function is defined as follows

$$J (\theta) := \sum_{t=1}^L \Big( x_t - \sum_{n=1}^N c_n \, \underbrace{\exp \left( -\left(\frac{t-n}{\theta}\right)^2 \right)}_{=: \varphi_{tn} (\theta)}\Big)^2 = \sum_{t=1}^L \Big( x_t - \sum_{n=1}^N c_n \, \varphi_{tn} (\theta) \Big)^2$$

Can somebody help me solve for $\theta$? I am a novice at solving optimization problems, so could somebody please tell me how do I get started to solve this problem using method such as Quasi Newton?

First few steps (edit):

\begin{align}
\begin{split}\label{eq:2}
    \frac{dJ}{d\theta}{}=& 0\\
         {\sum_{t}\frac{d}{d\theta}\left( x(t) - \sum_{n=0}^{N-1} c_{n} e^{-\left(\frac{t-n}{\theta}\right)^2} \right) ^{2}}=& 0 \\
{\sum_{t}-2 \left( x(t) - \sum_{n=0}^{N-1} c_{n} e^{-\left(\frac{t-n}{\theta}\right)^2} \right) \left( \sum_{n=0}^{N-1} c_{n} \frac{d}{d \theta} e^{-\left(\frac{t-n}{\theta}\right)^2}\right)}=& 0 \\
{\sum_{t}-4 \left( x(t) - \sum_{n=0}^{N-1} c_{n} e^{-\left(\frac{t-n}{\theta}\right)^2} \right) \left( \sum_{n=0}^{N-1} c_{n}  e^{-\left(\frac{t-n}{\theta}\right)^2} \frac{(t-n)^2}{\theta^3}\right)}=& 0 \\
\end{split}\\
\end{align}

2nd edit:
Let $\Phi (\theta)$ be the $m \times n$ matrix whose $(i,j)$-th entry is $\varphi_{ij} (\theta)$. Hence, cost function $J$ can be written more succinctly as follows

$$J (\theta) := \left\| \Phi (\theta) \, \mathrm c - \mathrm x \right\|_2^2 = \left( \Phi (\theta) \, \mathrm c - \mathrm x \right)^\top \left( \Phi (\theta) \, \mathrm c - \mathrm x \right)$$

whose first derivative is

$$J ' (\theta) = 2 \, \left( \Phi (\theta) \, \mathrm c - \mathrm x \right)^\top  \Phi ' (\theta) \, \mathrm c$$ 
 $J(\theta)$ over the range of $\theta$ is shown in the plot below:
[image]

P.S Matlab code to generate $J(\theta)$

```
L = 144; % Length of the signal

t = 0:L-1;
a = 1; % time shift factor
n = 0:L/a-1; %time shift index


x = ((-(pi*(t-20).^2)./16.^2))';

theta = 4:4:256;  % differnt variance in samples
D = zeros(L,length(n)); % ,matrix containing time-shifted gaussian

J = zeros(length(theta),1);
for i =1:length(theta)

     for t=1:length(n)
         D(:,t) = TimeShiftedGaussianMatrix(L,a,theta(i),n(t));       
     end

  c = pinv(D)*x;


  J(i) = (norm(x-D*c))^2; 
end

plot(theta,J); hold on

xlabel('\theta') ylabel('||x-\Phi(\theta)c||^2')


function atom = TimeShiftedGaussianMatrix(Lt,a,theta,n)

atom = zeros(Lt,1);
t = 0:Lt-1;
for i = 1:length(t)

 atom(i,1) = exp(-(pi*(t(i)-n*a).^2)./theta.^2);
end

end
```

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo  $c_n$ is a scalar. Also I am looking for analytical solution for $\theta$. I am not sure how to proceed.

Comment: Maybe you should take $L_2$ norm of this expression no minimize the difference between the $x(t)$ signal and its decomposition in $e^{\left(\frac{t-n}{\theta}\right)^2}$ terms, other wise $J$ will depend on time, which does not make sense

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo is it correct now?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo I am assuming discrete set for now. And I am quite lost on how to explicitly obtain $\theta$ from this step. Could you please me help with that?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo $t$ is a time index.i.e.,$t = 1,2..,L$

Comment: Yes, you are right. But still I don't have a clue as how to obtain $\theta$ from this since it not straight forward as in other cases like taking derivative of $J$ with respect to $c$ and equating to 0 to solve for c, is it?

Comment: Plot $J$ for $\theta$ over the range of interest. Would be interesting to see how "wild" $J$ is. Once you're done, edit your question and include the plot. It would also be nice to have some context, some background and motivation. Where does this question come from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Applying chain rule:

\begin{align}
\begin{split}\label{eq:1}
    \frac{dJ}{d\theta}{}=& \frac{d}{d\theta}\left( x(t) - \sum_{n=0}^{N-1} c_{n} e^{-\left(\frac{t-n}{\theta}\right)^2} \right) ^{2}\\
         {}=&-2 \left( x(t) - \sum_{n=0}^{N-1} c_{n} e^{-\left(\frac{t-n}{\theta}\right)^2} \right) \left( \sum_{n=0}^{N-1} c_{n} \frac{d}{d \theta} e^{-\left(\frac{t-n}{\theta}\right)^2}\right) \\
{}=&-4 \left( x(t) - \sum_{n=0}^{N-1} c_{n} e^{-\left(\frac{t-n}{\theta}\right)^2} \right) \left( \sum_{n=0}^{N-1} c_{n}  e^{-\left(\frac{t-n}{\theta}\right)^2} \frac{(t-n)^2}{\theta^3}\right) 
\end{split}\\
\end{align}

**Edit:** I am supposing that all involved variables are scalars

Comment: This is exactly where I was stuck. Could you please write few more steps?

Answer (score 0):

$$J (\theta) := \sum_{t=1}^m \Big( x_t - \sum_{k=1}^n c_k \, \underbrace{\exp \left( -\left(\frac{t-k}{\theta}\right)^2 \right)}_{=: \varphi_{tk} (\theta)}\Big)^2 = \sum_{t=1}^m \Big( x_t - \sum_{k=1}^n c_k \, \varphi_{tk} (\theta) \Big)^2$$

Let $\Phi (\theta)$ be the $m \times n$ matrix whose $(i,j)$-th entry is $\varphi_{ij} (\theta)$. Hence, cost function $J$ can be written more succinctly as follows

$$J (\theta) := \left\| \Phi (\theta) \, \mathrm c - \mathrm x \right\|_2^2 = \left( \Phi (\theta) \, \mathrm c - \mathrm x \right)^\top \left( \Phi (\theta) \, \mathrm c - \mathrm x \right)$$

whose first derivative is

$$J ' (\theta) = 2 \, \left( \Phi (\theta) \, \mathrm c - \mathrm x \right)^\top  \Phi ' (\theta) \, \mathrm c$$

One can then attempt to solve $J ' (\theta) = 0$ using, say, [Newton-Raphson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method).